# Permalink to a Gmail's minimal thread view

Tags: gmail

In Gmail you can link to a specific thread, from that thread you can open it in a new window. I'd like to link straight to that window. I enjoy the minimal look and I get distracted if I see my inbox has unread messages.

When I copy the URL for the thread window and paste it into a new tab it doesn't load. What URL do I need to use to link straight to the thread window?

Comment: You mean a window like this: http://i.imgur.com/wQyaX.png?1 ?

Comment: "I get distracted if I see my inbox has unread messages." - There used to be a lab feature that hid the unread count - although that doesn't appear to be available anymore!?

Answer (score 1):

If the link does not work, that probably means Google doesn't want you to visit that page without coming from the Gmail homepage.

That being the case, I fear you won't find a way around.

If you like the minimal look, this Chrome Extension maybe can help you: [Minimalist for Everything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmihblnpomgpjkfddepdpdafhhepdbek) (fusion of former "Minimalist for Gmail" and others).