# Private links to Gmail messages/threads

Tags: gmail

I keep a personal wiki. Very often, I want to reference email messages/threads in a wiki page. I'm a Gmail user, and from what I can tell there is no "clean" way to link to a particular message in Gmail. Messages and threads don't seem to have unique ID that is exposed in the Gmail interface. Am I missing something? What's a good way to store a link to a Gmail message and/or thread?

Comment: It doesn't seem like google offers this feature. The only thing close is the `show original` button under the `More` menu. I don't think that this would work very well for your use though.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142511/88163 , https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30768/88163 , https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/116748/88163